# Apache on localhost needs restart at every boot

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, localhost

I've set up a couple of test sites to run on my desktop Mandriva 2010, some of them fetch part of their content from the www (i.e. Wordpress RSS plugins, Twitter API, etc).

However, at every boot they're unable to connect and retrieve data: I have to restart the httpd service to make them work.

Nothing serious, but a little frustrating.
Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the boot order of your services?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look where in your init apache is being started. You may just need to knock it down a few places to make it start later in the boot process.

Another (less beautiful) way could be to add someting to `/etc/rc.local` to kick apache once the rest of init has finished.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like apache might be coming up before networking has been fully established. You probably need to add a delay to the apache startup sequence. That could be as simple as adding a `sleep 15` statement to the "start" clause of the apache init script.

Answer (score 0):

Also check log files:

1. `/var/log/`
2. `/var/log/httpd`